# Pretty basic SQL query involving count

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following schema

```
Company:
-> company_id
-> company_name

Building_to_company:
-> building_id
-> company_id
```

So each building has its own id as well as a company id which relates it to a single company.

the following query gives two columns -- one for the company name, and then its associated buildings.

```
SELECT company.company_name, building_to_company.building_id 
FROM company, building_to_company 
WHERE company.company_id = building_to_company.company_id;
```

The returned table would look something like this:

```
Company Name | Building Id
Smith Banking  2001
Smith Banking  0034
Smith Banking  0101
Smith Banking  4055
Reynolds       8191
TradeCo        7119
TradeCo        8510
```

So that's all simple enough.

But I need to do something a bit different. I need 2 columns. One for the company name and then on the right the number of buildings it owns. And then for a little extra challenge I only want to list companies with 3 or less buildings.

At this point the only real progress I've made is coming up with the query above. I know I some how have to use count on the building_id column and count the number of buildings associated with each company. And then at that point I can limit things by using something like `WHERE x < 4`

Comment: what kind of sql is this? sql server or not?

Comment: try group by company_id having count(*) < 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've basically got it in words already. Assuming `company_name` is unique, all you have to add to your explanation to get it to work is a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT company.company_name, COUNT(building_to_company.building_id)
FROM company
INNER JOIN building_to_company 
    ON company.company_id = building_to_company.company_id
GROUP BY company.company_name
```

([SQL Fiddle demo of this query in action](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98a84/1))

---

To limit it to companies with 3 or less buildings, the key is you have to use a `HAVING` clause and not `WHERE`. This is because you want to filter based on the results of an aggregate (`COUNT`); simply put, `WHERE` filters come before aggregation and `HAVING` come after:

```
SELECT company.company_name, COUNT(building_to_company.building_id)
FROM company
INNER JOIN building_to_company 
    ON company.company_id = building_to_company.company_id
GROUP BY company.company_name
HAVING COUNT(building_to_company.building_id) < 4
```

([SQL Fiddle demo of this query in action](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98a84/2))

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this

```
SELECT c.company_name, count(b.building_id)
FROM 
  company as c, 
  building_to_company as b 
WHERE c.company_id = b.company_id
GROUP BY c.company_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Below SQL-statement to find the company name with its own building count in descending order.

```
SELECT company.company_name, count(building_to_company.building_id)
FROM company (nolock), building_to_company(nolock) 
WHERE company.company_id = building_to_company.company_id
group by  company.company_name
having count(building_to_company.building_id)<=3
order by count(building_to_company.building_id) desc
```

Kindly let me know if you have any issue. Thanks